# How must I write this code without error

Tags: visual-studio

I want to write code that writes something into a file but it says it can't. How can I fix this? Please help.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  MyBase.Load
    yes.Visible = False
    no.Visible = False
    Label1.Visible = False
    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    Label2.Visible = False
    Label3.Visible = False
    TextBox1.Visible = False
    TextBox2.Visible = False
    apply.Visible = False
    back.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Visible = False
    yes.Visible = True
    no.Visible = True
    Label1.Visible = True
    setings.Visible = False

End Sub
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles yes.Click
    Label1.Text = "dowloading"
    no.Visible = False
    yes.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles no.Click
    yes.Visible = False
    no.Visible = False
    Label1.Visible = False
    Button1.Visible = True
    setings.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub setings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles setings.Click
    Label2.Visible = True
    Label3.Visible = True
    TextBox1.Visible = True
    TextBox2.Visible = True
    apply.Visible = True
    back.Visible = True
    Button1.Visible = False
    setings.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub back_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles back.Click
    Label2.Visible = False
    Label3.Visible = False
    TextBox1.Visible = False
    TextBox2.Visible = False
    apply.Visible = False
    back.Visible = False
    Button1.Visible = True
    setings.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub apply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles apply.Click
    Dim forgepath = TextBox1.Text
    Dim savefolder = Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "crazydolphininstaller")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(savefolder)
    Dim configfolder = Path.Combine(savefolder, "config")
    Directory.CreateDirectory(configfolder)
    Dim configfile = Path.Combine(configfolder, "config.txt")
    File.Create(configfile)
    Using writer = New StreamWriter(configfile)
        writer.WriteLine(forgepath)
        writer.WriteLine(savefolder)

    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what the error says?

Comment: `"but it says it cant"` - Surely there's a *more specific* indication of a problem than that.  "It can't" isn't really a standard error message.

Comment: @David It's not even clear who is the "it" in "it says". The IDE? The compiler? The runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.Create creates the file and returns a FileStream opened for you. Thus the following StreamWriter finds the file opened and cannot write in it. Just remove the File.Create line and use the StreamWriter constructor that allows the overwriting of the file if it exists

```vb
Private Sub apply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles apply.Click
    Dim forgepath = TextBox1.Text
    Dim savefolder = Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "crazydolphininstaller")
    Dim configfolder = Path.Combine(savefolder, "config")
    ' Called just one time. All the folder missing will be created
    Directory.CreateDirectory(configfolder)
    Dim configfile = Path.Combine(configfolder, "config.txt")
    ' Not needed
    ' File.Create(configfile)

    ' Pass False as second parameter to overwrite the file if it exists
    Using writer = New StreamWriter(configfile, False)
        writer.WriteLine(forgepath)
        writer.WriteLine(savefolder)
    End Using
End Sub
```